# Retaining specific Time Machine backups

Tags: time-machine, backup, restore

I created several Time Machine backups while I was running Mavericks. I upgraded to Yosemite and also backed it up on the same backup drive. I now have multiple backups of Mavericks and Yosemite on the same drive.

I have not purchased Mavericks via App Store, so I will not be able to re-install it. Is there a way for me to preserve my Mavericks backups, so that I can restore the operating system and then restore files from the latest Yosemite backups?